# How to run multiple color bloom animations that run at the same time?

Tags: c#, windows, animation, uwp, windows-10

I've been trying out the new Windows.UI.Composition APIs lately and when using the color bloom animation, I've been trying to run four of them simultaneously from each side of the screen. I've been able to make all four of them run at a click of a button but the last transition I've started always takes over the display in the end for example:

This is what happens:

[image]

But what should happen is that all the colors should fill the screen at the same time. How would I be able to do that?

This is the code I used to start the animations:

```
private void surroundBloomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //all of these headers are actually textblocks I've placed on the sides of the grid.
        var header = topFlower;

        var headerPosition = topFlower.TransformToVisual(UICanvas).TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0d, 0d));

        var header2 = rightFlower;

        var header2Position = rightFlower.TransformToVisual(UICanvas).TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0d, 0d));

        var header3 = bottomFlower;

        var header3Position = bottomFlower.TransformToVisual(UICanvas).TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0d, 0d));

        var header4 = leftFlower;

        var header4Position = leftFlower.TransformToVisual(UICanvas).TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0d, 0d));




        //Uses values of the textBlock size


        var initialBounds = new Windows.Foundation.Rect()
        {
            Width = header.RenderSize.Width,
            Height = header.RenderSize.Height,
            X = headerPosition.X,
            Y = headerPosition.Y
        };

        var finalBounds = Window.Current.Bounds; // maps to the bounds of the current window
        //The code is super easy to understand if you set a break point here and 
        //check to see what happens step by step ;)
        surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)),  // the color for the circlular bloom
                             initialBounds,                                  // the initial size and position
                                   finalBounds);                             // the area to fill over the animation duration

        // Add item to queue of transitions

        initialBounds = new Rect()
        {
            Width = header2.RenderSize.Width,
            Height = header2.RenderSize.Height,
            X = header2Position.X,
            Y = header2Position.Y
        };

        surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 150, 0)),  // the color for the circlular bloom
                           initialBounds,                                  // the initial size and position
                                 finalBounds);                             // the area to fill over the animation duration

        initialBounds = new Rect()
        {
            Width = header3.RenderSize.Width,
            Height = header3.RenderSize.Height,
            X = header3Position.X,
            Y = header3Position.Y
        };

        surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0)),  // the color for the circlular bloom
                           initialBounds,                                  // the initial size and position
                                 finalBounds);                             // the area to fill over the animation duration

        initialBounds = new Rect()
        {
            Width = header4.RenderSize.Width,
            Height = header4.RenderSize.Height,
            X = header4Position.X,
            Y = header4Position.Y
        };

        surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255)),  // the color for the circlular bloom
                           initialBounds,                                  // the initial size and position
                                 finalBounds);                             // the area to fill over the animation duration
    }

   private void SurroundButtonTransition_ColorBloomTransitionCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Changes colour of background to "White Smoke " when 
        //the animations have finished.
        UICanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.WhiteSmoke);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you are trying out the new Windows.UI.Composition APIs lately and when using the color bloom animation.

Since you had not post your code about the `surroundButtonTransition` that I use the [`ColorBloomTransitionHelper`](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/blob/831b879459e83dede4249a909612c7c2d29b3f64/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2010586/TransitionAnimation-ColorBloom/ColorBloomTransitionHelper.cs) from the GitHub. It uses the  `ContainerVisual.Children.InsertAtTop` method to insert a new visual at the top of the visual collection.

Also there is no method to add new visual at the same zindex as other visual in `ContainerVisual.Children`. Please check the method in [VisualCollection class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.composition.visualcollection.aspx).

If you want all the colors should fill the screen at the same time, you should be able to change the alpha value of your color.

For example:

```
surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 0, 0)), initialBounds, finalBounds);
surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 150, 0)), initialBounds, finalBounds);
surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 255, 0)), initialBounds, finalBounds);
surroundButtonTransition.Start((Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 255)), initialBounds, finalBounds);
```